# How to make a std::vector<T> use an existing T* array without copying those values?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<unsigned char>` vec and a pre-allocated contiguous buffer of (unsigned char) with size (len), that I know it's beginning which is stored in an `unsigned char*` variable named `start`. I know I can use `std::copy(start,start+len,vec.begin())` to copy them into the vector, but can I do that without copying? Can I make `vec.begin()` point to start pointer? I have all the values already allocated in memory, and I do not want to have to copy them into the vector because I have a memory constraint.

The pointer and length are given to me via an external API, so I cannot change that.

Comment: could you give us some code to work from? It sounds like you might want a [`span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) or `view` instead.

Comment: Note that `std::copy(start,start+len,vec.begin())` is undefined behaviour if you haven't already done `vec.resize(len)`.

Comment: Just stick with the `std::vector` constructor. Like this: `std::vector<unsigned char> vec (start, start + len);`

Comment: @DimChtz Note that that does allocate the extra memory

Comment: This might be doable by hacking custom allocators in some very, very sketchy ways. However, this is really gross. Better solutions are: 1) just suck it up and copy into the vector. Is it really the end of the world to do this? 2) Give up on having a vector. The canonical way in C++ to pass this sort of thing is through pairs of iterators and this example actually illustrates why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no interface into vector to make it take ownership of your pre-existing buffer.  Even if you could shoe-horn it into the vector by using a custom allocator that provides this memory's address, the vector will consider it raw memory and overwrite it.

If it *must* be a vector, then you're out of luck without copying.

However, some sort of adaptive view on the existing buffer could give a container-like interface over your array without copying (such as the gsl::span as suggested in comments by Justin.)

```
gsl::span<int> s(myPtr, 4);
```

see https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL
and http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/03/07/guidelines-support-library-review-spant/

Comment: This would be a good answer on the duplicate target (naturally, you'd have to make sure it is rewritten to fit the context of it)

Comment: Microsoft has an `array_view` class, and there is a proposal for a `std::array_view` class to be added to the standard STL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to control the memory allocation of your vector, you will need to create your own allocator class to do that, and pass it as a template parameter like this :

```
std::vector<int, my_custom_allocator<int>> my_vector;
```

Here is a good tutorial on how to create your own allocator : [The Standard Librarian: What Are Allocators Good For?](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-what-are-allocato/184403759)